# Compare and sort data

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc

I have 2 blocks of data; Column A and B are one set and column D and E the second.

I need to compare column A to Column D and for every match copy from Column B to column E.

Problem is that column A and D are not exact the same so I can't just sort them.

Data is just numbers sometimes empty space i wrote some letters to try make is more clear

| Column A | Column B | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2 |  |
| 2 | b | 4 |  |
| 3 | c | 5 |  |
| 5 | d | 9 |  |
| 9 | e | 1 |  |

I need:

| Column A | Column B | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2 | b |
| 2 | b | 4 |  |
| 3 | c | 5 | d |
| 5 | d | 9 | e |
| 9 | e | 1 | a |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this: put this formula in each cell in E (example for E1):

```
vlookup(D1, $A$1:$V$5, 2, FALSE)
```

This should lookup for D1 in row A1-A5 and copy the value of the second cell in the row, only if it matches exactly.
It will give you an error in E2 because 4 is not in the list. If you don't want that, surround the formula by 'iferror':

```
iferror(vlookup(D1, $A$1:$V$5, 2, FALSE), "")
```

Comment: it will be D2 you need to look up ;)

Comment: This one works i just needed to change , to ; i guess its my foult for not specifying im using google doc exele

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this in E2 then drag down:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(D2,A:A,0),1),"")`

It's hard to tell from your before and after picture exactly what you wanted.

Comment: Let me try be a bit more clear I need to take whole column A and compare it to whole column D then for every match i need to take data form column B to column E 
If there is numer 1000 in column A and D i need to copy number form B to matching E 
Those 2 pares of columns are product numbers and quantity of products i need to match data form 2 deferent system.

Comment: this solution should work then, did you try it ?

Comment: yes i try it, it shows error

Comment: Still problem is not clear. GIven example is also confusing. The job appears to be very easy, but a precise explanation is needed.